# IntelliJ PHP debugger not connecting

Tags: php, macos, debugging, intellij-idea, phpstorm

I've set up php 5.6 and Apache on my Mac and have IntelliJ with the php plugin installed (2016.2). The problem is that the IDE doesn't want to connect to the local server.

I've added the following lines to my php.ini:

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension=/usr/local/Cellar/php56/5.6.24/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.remote_port = "9000"
```

and when I run `php -v` I get:

> Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
>       with Xdebug v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 2002-2016, by Derick Rethans

and `phpinfo()` shows

> xdebug.remote_enable On   On
>   xdebug.remote_port 9000 9000

But IntelliJ shows:

```
xdebug.remote_enable 0
```

I've checked, that I'm pointing to the right `php.ini` (checked path and other changes appear when the file is edited).

I tried all configurations (including with an IDE key) but nothing seems to work.

Is there a way I can check if the debugging is really working (i.e. is it the IDE not recognizing something or is the server faulty), because at this point I don't know what the problem may be.

Comment: *"The problem is that the IDE doesn't want to connect to the local server"* What do you mean by that **exactly**? If it's about PHP debugging .. then IDE **never** connects to local server (or whatever). it's xdebug that connects to debug client (IDE in our case). Please check how it works: https://xdebug.org/docs/remote

Comment: *"and when I run php -v I get:"* On some Mac setups (e.g. MAMP) as well as most Linux distribs PHP will use one php.ini for CLI and Apache will use different one. Therefore -- if you want to debug web page (via browser) then you need to check `phpinfo()` output captured via browser .. where you may see different php.ini used. The *"But IntelliJ shows: xdebug.remote_enable 0"* part just confirms that (at least gives a very strong hint in that direction).

Comment: Well, I've added what phpinfo() shows (it was through the browser), and the IDE says which php.ini it is using. By "it doesnt't connect" I mean, when I start the debugger, it doesn't hit any braekpoints, neither does it show any errors when I start/stop the local server

Comment: Just to be 100% clear: 1) please provide the header of `phpinfo()` output (everything before actual config) captured via browser 2) xdebug section as well.

Comment: Also -- how did you installed PHP? It might be conflicting with something else. Please 1) collect xdebug log for such unsuccessful debug session https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#remote_log 2) show results of `sudo lsof -nP -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN`. There is a chance that you will have php-fpm running on your computer .. .which uses TCP 9000 -- same port as xdebug -- #2 should clarify that. In such case -- changing xdebug port to 9001 (or similar) in both IDE and php.ini should solve the issue.

Comment: Well, you're right. php-fpm was using port 9000. I specified another port for debugging and that did the trick. Post it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way is to collect [xdebug log](https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#remote_log) for such unsuccessful debug session to see what it has to say. Sometimes debug does not work for you (IDE shows no reaction) but xdebug actually connects somewhere just fine (e.g. another service .. as described below).

There is a chance that you will have `php-fpm` running on your computer (that depends on how you installed your PHP -- what tool you have used for that). Php-fpm by default uses the same TCP 9000 port as xdebug does.

```
sudo lsof -nP -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN
```

Run this command in terminal -- it should tell (after filtering results on `9000` keyword) what services are already listening on that port.

If it's indeed `php-fpm` .. then changing xdebug port from default `9000` to any other (e.g. `9001` or any other usually unused port) in both IDE settings + php.ini will solve the issue.